# Having an issue with an SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm just having an issue with a query and I was wondering if this is right.

Query..

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, COUNT(first_name) FROM administrators
LEFT OUTER JOIN reviews ON administrators.username = reviews.author
group by first_name, last_name
```

The results...

[image]

My Tables ..

Administrator..

[image]

Thanks guys!

Comment: Please can you post/build the schema on sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com ?

Comment: so what's wrong with it? it seem like I answered before?

Comment: @ah_hau This is what it should be doing :/ (Thanks for the help before)

http://gyazo.com/74e53a421610c70607a04c3698d194a4

Comment: You probably want to `COUNT(reviews.id)` or something of the sort.

Comment: ARe those real user name / email addresses?

Comment: Please can you post/build the schema on sqlfiddle? So that we can help to create the query

Comment: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/548d2a/20), help to added sqlfiddle with simplified tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, COUNT(reviews.review_title) FROM administrators
LEFT OUTER JOIN reviews ON (administrators.first_name + ' ' + administrators.last_name) = reviews.author
group by first_name, last_name
```

Your join key is wrong. Your author in review table should map with first_name + space + last_name

---

UPDATE: 
Here is the updated query, din't notice MySQL cannot use + ' ' +, should use CONCAT, tested work this time.

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, COUNT(reviews.review_title)
FROM administrators
LEFT JOIN reviews ON CONCAT(administrators.first_name, ' ', administrators.last_name) = reviews.author
GROUP BY first_name, last_name
```

Update2 : 
Added sqlfiddle example : [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/548d2a/20)

Comment: Thanks but that didn't seem to work either ;( http://gyazo.com/1d89f3aee54af3b1ec231b50fb6fba2a

Comment: http://gyazo.com/4b1aaea4d8da33393ebe30f2da73477a ;( I don't know why it's not working D:

Comment: @Ellie, check again the updated query, it should work as expected now. The syntax is diff with MSSQL

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.first_name, a.last_name, COUNT(b.author) FROM administrators a LEFT OUTER JOIN reviews b ON a.first_name + " " + a.last_name= b.author group by b.author
```

this code is working in me, show me your administrator table

Comment: @ah_hau I don't have reviews in administrators :(

Comment: SELECT first_name, last_name, COUNT(reviews.review_title) FROM administrators
LEFT OUTER JOIN reviews ON administrators.username = reviews.author
group by first_name, last_name

this is what he mean

Comment: @CodeSlayer Is that to me?

Comment: @CodeSlayer This is the new result..  http://gyazo.com/4624f3d9516cb2553c8712a16825da07 :( Why isn't it working D:

Comment: i thought that's what you want, can you elaborate your problem?